# Use displayModeButtonItem for my own UIButton SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uisplitviewcontroller

My app use a splitViewcontroller. I removed the navigationBar of my DetailViewController. So I cannot use :

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
```

But I need my own button to display my MasterViewController in a popover like the leftBarButtonItem done.

I tried :

```
@IBAction func showAll() {
  rootViewController.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem().action
}
```

But it doesn't work.

EDIT :

I tried to add my own popover, with inside my masterViewController.

```
@IBAction func showAll(sender : UIButton!) {

    let popover = UIPopoverController(contentViewController:masterViewController)
    popover.presentPopoverFromRect(sender.frame, inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirection(), animated: true)
}
```

But the app crashes :

```
Application tried to present modally an active controller <DetailViewController: 0x7f8393d96540>
```

I don't understand because I need to display the popover in the view of detailViewController. How can I do otherwise?

Comment: This is a shot in the dark: try using `self.splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .PrimaryOverlay` in your `showAll` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works perfectly with @pbasdf solution :

```
@IBAction func showAll() {
    self.splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .PrimaryOverlay
    self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem().action
}
```